# How to add field Mask in GoogleApis Places

Tags: flutter, google-api, google-places-api

```
import 'package:googleapis/places/v1.dart';
import 'package:googleapis_auth/googleapis_auth.dart';
final http.Client client = clientViaApiKey(apikey);


final PlacesApi places = PlacesApi(client);

GoogleMapsPlacesV1SearchTextResponse res = await places.places.searchText(
        GoogleMapsPlacesV1SearchTextRequest(
          textQuery: "mcDonals Near Me",
          maxResultCount: 10,
          locationRestriction:
              GoogleMapsPlacesV1SearchTextRequestLocationRestriction.fromJson({
            "circle": {
              "center": {"latitude": 37.7937, "longitude": -122.3965},
              "radius": 500.0
            }
          }),
        ),
      );
```

That is my above code !
Error:

> DetailedApiRequestError(status: 400, message: FieldMask is a required parameter. See https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/system-parameters on how to provide it. As an example, you can set the header 'X-Goog-FieldMask' to value 'places.displayName', 'places.id' to ask for the display name and the place id of a place. You can also set the value to '*' in manual testing to get all the available response fields.

Comment: check the client library you are using not all of them support that.